# How Come my VLookup Returns 0 when there's Data in the column it should be pulling from

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Workbook with Two Sheets in it. One Sheet contains a Data connections that are stored inside of a Table. This is a set of Sample Data in the same format that my Data is arranged.

**Data Table**
[image: Data Connection Table]

The other sheet contains a raw copy-paste of the first 6 columns and the last column. As shown below.

**Raw Data**
[image]
I'm Performing this Lookup: 
`=VLOOKUP(M2,'Raw Data'!A1:G1195,6)`
and I'm returning 0 however if I change the column that is being examined to say `=VLOOKUP(M2,'Raw Data'!A1:G1195,1)` I get the correct result however attempting to put column 6 (Comment Column) the VLookUp only returns 0.

The Reason there's a VBA Tag on this is because I'm also attempting to do this via a Macro but both the Macro and this Hands-On lookup fail to properly return the correct results. (The Macro returns nothing)

EDIT: Upon further inspection, It seems when I add FALSE as the Fourth Argument I now return #N/A which means it can't find the matching entries at all.. I've played with it by removing FALSE and it seems it is referencing the Wrong rows entirely somehow.

Comment: I assume that first screenshot shows columns starting with A. ...So Column F (`6` in the `Vlookup()`) is the "Comments" column...where there's no data.  So it might match your lookup, but will "correctly" return a `0` since there's no data to return.

Comment: Check Raw Data for any hidden columns? Your formula works fine for me.

Comment: @BruceWayne The Raw Data should be placing the Comments Back into the Table. I perform a Data refresh and then the Vlookup will copy back the Comments as they're not listed on the Data Source

Comment: If first screenshot is for "Raw Data" then ignore my above comment. I assumed that you copy the data from 1st screenshot into `Raw Data` which is your 2nd screenshot.

Comment: @SiddharthRout The Sheets have no Hidden Columns. The First Sheet goes from A->M without any deviation and the Second Sheet A->G without any deviation. Outside of that shouldn't matter as I'm only concerned with data in those Columns.  I also meant the First Screenshot is the Table the Second is Raw Data

Comment: The things that stick out to me are that you are using an inexact match search (not using FALSE as the fourth argument of vlookup), that column M for the key is the unique id whereas you are matching against the department in the raw data, and that you are using `'Raw Data'!A1:G1195` and not `'Raw Data'!$A$1:$G$1195`, which would get messed up when copying and pasting. However as you are getting correct results with other columns, that may all be red herrings.

Comment: @Deepstop I was just playing with it by adding FALSE as the Fourth Argument and I now return #N/A for everything. I also modified the the Sheet reference to match the what you referenced and I still returned #N/A This is the Vlookup that now just returns #N/A `=VLOOKUP(M2, 'Raw Data'!$A$1:$G$1195, 7, FALSE)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Could there be an issue with my VLOOKUP formula? If it isn't returning the correct row.

Comment: If you are seeing `#N/A` then it is because you are trying to find the value in column M in `Raw Data` column A. As those values don't match at all you will get `#N/A`. VLOOKUP tries to find the match in the first column of the range specified in the 2nd argument, which in your example is the Department. You were getting (probably incorrect) results previously because you weren't using an exact match.

Comment: @Deepstop `=VLOOKUP(M2, 'Raw Data'!$A$1:$G$1195, 7, FALSE)` Shouldn't this lookup be looking for M2 in RawData and returning column 7

Comment: No, it is looking just in the first column of `'Raw Data'!$A$1:$G$1195`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLOOKUP searches for the value of the 1st argument in the *first column* of the range specified in the second argument. In your example, you are using column M as the value to look for, and column A as the values to check. These are not matching. You have illustrated this by adding `FALSE` as the 4th argument to VLOOKUP which forces an exact match and found that nothing matches at all because nothing in `Raw Data` column A matches column M of your Data Table.

Not having FALSE as the 4th argument changes the behaviour to do a closest match search, which is not what you want and is creating erroneous results.

Unfortunately, with VLOOKUP using the first column, and `Unique ID` being the last column in the raw data, you are faced with a bit of a challenge in creating the correct VLOOKUP formula, because the column you want is to the left of the column you are looking up. If you can move `Unique ID` to the leftmost column in `Raw Data` then it will work as intended. You could also create a hidden leftmost column that replicates column M. If you can't rearrange your data you will need to approach the problem differently.

A nice thing to do is also to declare the range as a named range (e.g. `raw_data`) instead of using cell references. If you are pulling the data from a database Excel will give the range a name automatically and you could also use that.

Comment: My Macro uses a Range, I'll work toward fixing Unique ID's Location I left it in the last Column because I couldn't figure how to shift the cells from the Copy over.

Comment: Cut and paste the entire column. You should be able to record it and see how to code it. Let me know how it turns out.

Comment: It Worked thank you, I reversed the Macro's steps and ran it and the Macro executed what I needed/wanted. I didn't know the First Columns needed to be match but it seems it has all worked out finally.